# Calculate percentage of a return value against the sale value in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, percentage, powerbi-desktop

I have a matrix in which there are companies, sale value, and return value.

[image]

I want to calculate that **what percentage of the return value is from sales value**

The sales value can be negative because there can be no sales.

How can I do it?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do this with measure

```
Percentage = sum(Table[Return value])/sum(Table[SALES VALUE])
```

Then select measure and click on % symbol in Measure tools. Numbers will be displayed
in %.

Comment: It's giving me percentage in minus as well

Comment: If you want display 0% for negative sales values you can modify measure to

`Percentage = if(sum(Table[SALES VALUE]) > 0, DIVIDE(sum(Table[Return value]),sum(Table[SALES VALUE])),0)`

Comment: I have used `ABS`

Comment: Can you please look into one of my new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69299604/6854117) related to power-bi?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this example, Its posted in powerbi community.

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Measure-to-calculate-average-in-line-stack-bar-chart/m-p/1608563#M650205

Comment: Can you please look into one of my new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69299604/6854117) related to power-bi?